# PHP - получить url страницы

Tags: php, html, url

На странице выполняется php скрипт. 
Адрес страницы типа: site.com/razdel/index.html 
Скрипт лежит в корне, в отдельной папке. 
Советы вроде `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ведут к файлу скрипта 
"/sendmail/sendmail.php"
Как **в php** получить адрес **html страницы**?

Любые манипуляции с файлами, их расположением и структурой отвергаются.

Comment: А зачем у вас скрипт подменяет содержимое `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: @Visman Может потому что скрипт находится в отдельной папке?

Comment: Да просто интересно, зачем скрипту менять содержимое этой переменной. Обычно на ее основе делается роутинг и соответственно в ней можно увидеть какая страница сайта открыта. А `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` это предыдущая страница :) Та с которой текущая открывалась.

Comment: @Visman во как. Да, тогда не совсем то, что нужно. Насчет подмены ничего сказать не могу, скрипт взял с прошлого проекта, которым другой программист занимался.

Comment: А как насчет того чтобы использовать .htaccess ?

Comment: @Y.Pavlinskiy а что он мне даст? Мне нужно определить с какой страницы было отправлено письмо.

Comment: @Visman Не знаю, что и зачем он там меняет. Но в любом случае  `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` указывает на текущую страницу. Может потому что она является предыдущей по отношению к замененному значению.

Comment: Из названия `sendmail.php` я предположу, что это отправка письма.Отправка письма видимо у вас возможна с любой страницы сайта. Возможно даже там pop-up выскакивает с формой письма и потом идет отправка через ajax на сервер. В таком случае с поведением на сервере все верно. В `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` отображается та страница с которой была отправлена форма на `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` = `/sendmail/sendmail.php`. Но лучше было бы в форме отправки добавить невидимое поле содержащее адрес страницы отправки, так как не всегда браузер пользователя отправляет на сервер `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: И на сервере уже использовать содержимое этого невидимого поля для своих нужд.

Comment: @Visman все верно предположили. Если буду переделывать, вместо невидимого поля думаю получать url в js и передавать через ajax

Answer (score 6):

```
echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Отсюда взял: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php

```
// URL адрес сайта
$url = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') ? 's' : '') . '://';
$url = $url . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
define('URL', $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

```
$page = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Про синтаксис - [ТЫК](https://www.php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing.simple)

Если хотите поддержку HTTP и HTTPS, то используйте код ниже

```
$page = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") 
    . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

> PS. использование этого кода имеет последствия для безопасности .
> Клиент может установить HTTP_HOST и REQUEST_URI в любое произвольное
> значение, которое он хочет.

Источник - [ТЫК](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768831)

Answer (score 0):

Возвращает то что нужно `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: Возвращает то что нужно, если ты с целевой страницы и отправляешь запрос.

Answer (score -4):

```
header("location :http://site.com/razdel/index.html ");
```

Вроде должно помочь.